# Search an uploaded document asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am looking for any help, so i am currently uploading a file which is either a pdf or a docx to a file server and storing the address in a sql database. I am now trying to allow the user to search the whole database and also the text in the documents that have been uploaded. I am struggling to find any solutions using asp.net core. 
Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Depending how many documents you have this is probably going to be **slow as hell**.

You will want to look into building a full-text-index like lucene or importing the contents of the files into a SQL full text index.

There isn't a pre-made way to do this as it is complicated depending on specific requirements

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, at the moment it is only going to be around 10-20 documents. I have looked into Lucene tried to get my head around it doesn’t seem like much support for asp.net core

Comment: If its only 10-20 documents then just dump the text into a SQL table and query as you usually would... Lucene does support .net core as far as I am aware, but even if not you can set a separate server and send it a query, you use something like ElasticSearch which should do some of the config for you

Comment: You could try something like https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1251842/Working-with-the-dtSearch-ASP-NET-Core-WebDemo-S-2

Alternatively you could save your documents in your sql server database and create a full text index for the documents.